# how to trace a mobile when switched off using imei

Tags: lost-phone, gps-tracking

how to tracre a mobile when switched off using imei.my phone is moto E.I can trace my mobile when it is switched on +location on + mobile date on . I can trace ,ring and even wipe my data also when these are all on.but the only problem is to trace my mobile when it is switched off.

Answer (score 3):

A switched-off phone is, well, switched off. That means all its radio modules are off. That means that it is not connected to any external equipment. That means that you cannot track it.

BTW you also cannot track your phone if it's in flight mode *(I mean here full flight mode with wi-fi switched off)*.